# Replace every character with an element

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

**This is what I have**

```
$str = 'Just a <span class="green">little</span> -text åäö width 123#';
```

**This is what I need**

Results in spans and spaces, might be newlines as well.

```
$result = '<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span> <span class="green"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span>';
```

You might wonder what I can possible be needing this for. I want to build a thing where ever character is represented by a block. Will look a bit like Defrag on Windows XP.

**Question**

- Replace every character with `<span></span>`.
- Do not touch the HTML span that already exists in the string (might be hard?). There can be more than one HTML element.
- Do not touch spaces and newline.
- Regexp should do it? or Xpath?

**What have I done so far?**

I have found articles about the regexp but not replacing every character (excerpt space and newline)

```
$result = preg_replace("/???/", "<span></span>", $str);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: try `preg_replace("/([^:space:\n])/", "<span></span>", $str);` [] is a set of characters, ^ is NOT, :space: or \s is a space \n is newline

Comment: The "don't touch the HTML that already exists in the string" part is where regex solutions cause problems. You really want to use a DOM parser, to iterate only over the textnodes and apply a `/\S/` -> `<span></span>` replacement on those. [Here is a good overview of your DOM-parsing options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml)

Comment: Is there only one HTML span or are there more ?

Comment: There can be more than one. I updated my question information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for hacky regex-solutions. A simple for loop with a state machine should do just fine:

```
define('STATE_READING', 1);
define('STATE_TAG', 2);

$str = 'Just a <span class="green">little</span> -text åäö width 123#';
$result = '';

$state = STATE_READING;
for($i = 0, $len = strlen($str); $i < $len; $i++) {
    $chr = $str[$i];

    if($chr == '<') {
        $state = STATE_TAG;
        $result .= $chr;
    } else if($chr == '>') {
        $state = STATE_READING;
        $result .= $chr;
    } else if($state == STATE_TAG || strlen(trim($chr)) === 0) {
        $result .= $chr;
    } else {
        $result .= '<span></span>';
    }
}
```

This loop is just keeping track if we are reading a tag or a single character. If it is a tag (or whitespace), append the actual character, otherwise append `<span></span>`.

Results in:

```
<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span> <span class="green"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
```

Comment: I prefer it over magical numbers. `$state == STATE_TAG` shows the intent better than `$state == 2` or `$state == 'x'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
$str = 'Just a <span class="green">little</span> -text åäö width 123#';

function replacement($matches) {
            if (strlen($matches[0]) == 1) 
            {
                return "<span></span>";
            }
            else 
           {
               return $matches[0];
           }
}

$result = preg_replace_callback("~<span.*?<\s*/\s*span>|\S~", "replacement", $str);
print_r($result);
```

This is just calculate the replacement string dependent on the match. If the length of the match is 1 (a non whitespace character has been found), then replace with the "span" tags, else a span tag has been found, reinsert this.

Comment: @Waygood, no because `\S` is a non-whitespace character, newlines belong to the whitespace characters, they are not matched.

Comment: does anything else belong to 'whitespace characters' too? if its not just a space and new line, e.g. tab \t, then the results will be wrong?

Comment: @Waygood of course a tab is also a whitespace character, since it prints only whitespace. If this is a problem, a negated character class should be used `~<span.*?<\s*/\s*span>|[^ \r\n]~`. This would match really every character that is not a space or a newline.

Answer (score 1):

is it a requirement to use only one regular expression?

if not - you could replace substring which you need to safe with some unique character, execute replacing by regexp, put substring instead of that unique char.

Just like this:

```
$str2 = str_replace('<span class="green">little</span>', '$', $str);
$str3 = preg_replace("/([^\s\n\$])/", "<span></span>", $str2);
$result = str_replace('$', '<span class="green">little</span>', $str3);
```

see live demo http://codepad.viper-7.com/7wu9fd

**UPD:**

Perhaps it should be considered just as hint. My suggestion was to store substring(s) what needed to be stored, replace everything you need, put stored values back into string.

```
$str = 'Just a <span class="green">little</span> -text åäö width 123#';

preg_match_all('/<[^>]+>/', $str, $matches);
$storage=array();
for($i=0, $n=count($matches[0]); $i<$n; $i++)
{
    $key=str_repeat('$', $i+1);
    $value=$matches[0][$i];
    $storage[$key]=$value;
    $str=str_replace($value, $key, $str);
}
$storage=array_reverse($storage);

$str = preg_replace("/([^\s\n\$])/", "<span></span>", $str);
foreach($storage as $k=>$v)
{
    $str=str_replace($k, $v, $str);
}
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

working demo is there http://codepad.viper-7.com/L4YZOz

Comment: Interesting solution. Too bad it's not an option for me. The 'little' can be anything and should be converted to spans as well.

Answer (score 0):

While this is probably possible with a regex, but I'd go with a loop. Example code below is for single-byte character sets but can be modified for multi-byte (e.g. UTF-16) or variable-byte (e.g. UTF-8) character set.

```
$input = 'Just a <span class="green">little</span> -text åäö width 123#';
$output = '';
$length = strlen($input);
$i = 0;
$matches = array(); // preg_match variable
// While for finer control
while($i < $length) {
    // Check for start of span tag, check for < character first for speed-up
    if($input[$i] == "<" && preg_match("#<span[^>]*>.*</span>#siU", substr($input, $i), $matches) == 1) {
        // Skip the span tag
        $i = $i + strlen($matches[0]);
        $output .= $matches[0];
    } else {
        $output .= "<span></span>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

[Working example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fa0-r9e)

Comment: Haven't tested the code very well, might be some boundary conditions left, but the idea should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hack but try this:

```
$str="Just a <span class=\"green\">little</span> -text åäö\n width 123#";

// get all span tags
if(preg_match_all("/(\<span.*\<\/span\>)/", $str, $matches))
{
    // replace spans with #
    $str=preg_replace_all("/(\<span.*\<\/span\>)/", "#", $str);

    //print_r($matches);
}
// replace all non spaces, CR and #
$str=preg_replace("/[^\s\n#]/", "<span></span>", $str);
// replenish the matched spans
while(list($key,$value)=each($matches[0]))
{
    $str=preg_replace('/#/', $value, $str, 1);
}
```

Comment: Won't this break if `$str` contains a `#` in it somewhere between two span tags?

Comment: Yes, if there is a # outside of a <span> set, that's why its a hack

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I came up with using [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$str = 'Just a <span class="green">little</span>-text åäö width 123#<span>aaa</span> lol';

// This requires PHP 5.3+
$output = preg_replace_callback('#.*?(<span[^>]*>.*?</span>)|.*#is', function($m){
    if(!isset($m[1])){return preg_replace('/\S/', '<span></span>', $m[0]);}
    $array = explode($m[1], $m[0]);
    $array = preg_replace('/\S/', '<span></span>', $array);
    return(implode($m[1], $array));
}, $str);
echo($output);
```

Output:

```
<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span> <span class="green">little</span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span>aaa</span> <span></span><span></span><span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a hacky regex method.  This is a solid, concise, one-line-one-function-call solution that avoids having to iterate a battery of conditions on each character in a string, preserves tags, and cares for multi-byte characters.

alexn's solution does not maintain the visible character length of `åäö`.  His solution will print 6 opening and closing span tags to screen instead of just 3.  This is because `mb_` functions are not used.  On this topic, be wary of any methods on this page that are not using `mb_` prefixed string functions.

My suggested solution will leverage the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` technique to ignore/disqualify all encountered tags and then only match non-white-space characters in the string.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/637bf7ec06e21e8e12561040c86b608122a4a0de))

```
$str = 'Just a <span class="green">little</span> -text åäö width 123#';
var_export(preg_replace('/<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\S/','<span></span>',$str));  // no "u" flag means åäö will be span x6
echo "\n";
var_export(preg_replace('/<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\S/u','<span></span>',$str)); // "u" flag means åäö will be span x3
```

Output: (scroll right to see the impact of the unicode flag on the pattern)

```
'<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span> <span class="green"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>'
// notice the number of replacements for åäö ->-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------111111111111122222222222223333333333333444444444444455555555555556666666666666
'<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span> <span class="green"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>'
// notice the number of replacements for åäö ->-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------111111111111122222222222223333333333333
```

Comment: @JensTörnell How many sets of span tags did you want to see when replacing the multibyte characters? `åäö` should become 3 sets or 6 sets?  It seems to me that you would only want three because there is no added benefit to six.